# How to embed Images in Xamarin Forms Grid Layout

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I am trying t create a xamarin.forms grid layout, and embed an image into it. The only docs I can find about image embedding is [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Local_Images), on the Xamarin Site.

```
var beachImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
beachImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("waterfront.jpg");
```

However, this seems to require setting up the image as a variable and having it in a stack layout.

I however, am trying to customise the [following](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Grid/) model grid layout, which when I add the code to create a variable and then define it's image source, is throwing up errors.

In XAML, it is pretty simple:

```
<Image Source="logo.jpg"/>
```

I would like to know if there is an equivalent for this in Xamarin.Forms compatible C#.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us what specific errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but you could simply do:

```
var beachImage = new Image();
beachImage.Source = "logo.jpg";
```

It is the same as its XAML equivalent:

```
<Image Source="logo.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Well, the second one is a XAML command? I would like something like that, for C#. If I out the second line into my code, it throws up compiler errors, saying it wasn't expecting a `<` etc.

Comment: The first two lines are the equivalent C# for the XAML in the 3rd line.

Comment: `grid.Children.Add(new Image { 
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                Source = "logo.png", 
            }, 0, 1, 0, 1);`
I have put logo.png and logo@2x.png into the resources file in iOS and not done anything for the core file. I have also put it into the android file. It compiles, but is not showing the image when deployed, have I done something wrong?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/